# Debugging NSImage's failure to open a BMP image file

Tags: swift, nsimage

```objective-c
var fileManager:NSFileManager = NSFileManager()
var imagePath:String = "/Users/dumbledad/Documents/flower.bmp"
var msg:String = (fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(imagePath) ? " exists" : " does not exist")
print(imagePath + msg)
var imageNS = NSImage(named: imagePath)!
```

When I run the app I see

```
/Users/dumbledad/Documents/flower.bmp exists
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

and the error `Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`.

How do I debug why NSImage is failing to open the image file? It does display correctly if I open the image in Preview from Finder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the `NSImage(named:)` initializer, the image file has to be embedded in your Xcode project.

Example for an image name "hello.jpg":

```
let img = NSImage(named: "hello")
```

This will only work if the image exists inside your app.

Also currently you're passing the *path* to the NSImage initializer, not just the file name as you should with this `named` initializer.

On the other hand, to load an image from the filesystem (this time, not included in your app), you can use `NSImage(contentsOfFile:)` with your path or `NSImage(contentsOfURL:)` with an NSURL of your path.